# Как спозиционировать элементы в Row?

Tags: listview, flutter

Есть какой-то способ выровнять средний элемент (время), чтобы в каждом тайле он был на одном уровне?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        element['deadline'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: element['overdue'] ? Colors.redAccent : null,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Text(element['estimate'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: Text(element['stage_id']),
                    ),

                ],),
```

Апдейт:

```
child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Text(
                            element['deadline'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: element['overdue']
                                    ? Colors.redAccent
                                    : null,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Text(
                            element['estimate'],
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 4,
                          child: Text(element['stage_id'], textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам осталось только правильно `Container` разместить и `padding` отредактировать. Ещё у `Expanded` есть `flex`, с помощью которого можно изменять пространства между элементами.

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          element['deadline'],
          style: TextStyle(
              color: element['overdue'] ? Colors.redAccent : null,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          element['estimate'],
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(element['stage_id']),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. Добавил flex и textAlign.